# Node.js EBADF error when writing file using writable stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I tried to use Node.js to process a 500MB Apache log file, converting its syntax from

```
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
```

to

```
ip.ip.ip.ip - - 02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1 302 26
```

, then write to another text file.

For better memory control and performance, I used `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream`, but only managed to write the first line into `output.txt`, because the script ends with an error:

`{ [Error: EBADF, write] errno: 9, code: 'EBADF' }`

Here I posted some info that may help debug.

Head of `input.txt`:

```
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:18 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
```

Content of `output.txt`:

```
ip.ip.ip.ip - - [02/Aug/2012:05:01:17 -0600] "GET /path/of/access/ HTTP/1.1" 302 26
```

The whole script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data ='';
var n=0;                    //For line control
var r = fs.createReadStream('./input.txt',{
    encoding: 'ascii',
    start:0,
    // end: 100000,
});
var w = fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt',{
    encoding:'ascii'
});
function put(line){         //write into w;
    ++n;
    w.write(line+'\n');
}
function end(){
    r.destroy();
    w.destroy();
}
function onData(chunk){
    var hasNewline = chunk.indexOf('\n')!==-1;
    if(hasNewline){
        var arr = chunk.split('\n');
        var first = arr.shift();
        var last = arr.pop();
        data+=first;
        put(data);          //write a complete line
        arr.forEach(function(line){
            put(line);      //write a complete line
        });
        data=last;
    }else{
        data+=chunk;
    }
    if(n>100){
        end();
    }
}
function onErr(e){
    console.log(e);
}

r.addListener( "data", onData);
r.addListener( "end", end);
r.addListener('error',onErr);
w.addListener('error',onErr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two issues that I can see.

The first is that your `end` function calls `destroy` on the ReadStream, but in the general case this is triggered from the `end` event, which means that the stream is already closing, and it is going to call `destroy` automatically. That means that `r.destroy` is going to be called twice, triggering an error. This is the cause of the error you are seeing printed.

The second issue is that you are calling `destroy` on the WriteStream. I suggest you go read the docs for that: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_destroy_1

Specifically `Any queued write data will not be sent`, which is why you are missing some of your output.

Basically, you should ONLY call `destroy` on the ReadStream if you want it to close early, like in your `n > 100` case. Then you want to use WriteStream's `end` instead, so the stream has time to write all of the buffered data.

Here is a simplified version, which I think should work the same. I'd also not bother binding `error` since errors are automatically printed to the console anyway.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data ='';
var n=0;                    //For line control

var r = fs.createReadStream('./input.txt',{
    encoding: 'ascii',
    start:0,
    // end: 100000,
});

var w = fs.createWriteStream('./output.txt',{
    encoding:'ascii'
});

r.addListener( "data", function(chunk){
    data += chunk;
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    data = lines.pop();

    lines.forEach(function(line){
      if (!r.readable) return; // If already destroyed
      if (n >= 100) {
          // Stop any more 'data' events and close the file.
          // This will also trigger 'close' below and close the writestream.
          r.destroy();
          return;
      }

      n++;
      w.write(line + '\n');
    });
});
r.addListener( "end", function(){
    // When we hit the end of the file, close the write stream,
    // and write any remaining line content
    w.write(data);
});
r.addListener("close", function(){
  w.end();
});
```

Comment: Ahh, it works. Thank you, it looks like a typical newbie mistake.