# Write after end, nodejs gridFS writestream error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

With the code below I am able to upload an image to mogodb one time, if I try a second time I get an error.

I did some research and its because the writestream is closing [NODEJS writeStream error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035753/nodejs-writestream-error)

```
conn.once('open', function () {

    var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);

    app.post('/upload', function(req,res){

        form.on('part', function(part){
            if(!part.filename) return;
            size = part.byteCount;
            fileName = part.filename;
        });

        form.on('file', function(name,file){

            var tempfile = file.path;
            var origname = fileName;

            var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: origname });

            fs.createReadStream(tempfile).on('end', function () {
                res.send('<p><h1>Upload Complete!</h1><p>');
            }).on('error', function () {
                res.send('Error, upload failed!');
            }).pipe(writestream);

        });

        form.parse(req);

    });


    app.get('/image/:id', function(req,res){

        console.log(req.params.id)
        gfs.createReadStream({_id:req.params.id}).pipe(res);

    });

});
```

The error message looks like this

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Chat-App\node_modules\multiparty\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:161:12)
    at Form.Writable.write (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Chat-App\node_modules\multiparty\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:208:5)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:582:24)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:591:7)
    at _stream_readable.js:559:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

So it looks like multiparty is problematic with my code. My question is how do I solve this should I change my post method to run the code on an id?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();
```

inside

```
app.post('/upload', function(req,res){...});
```

do not declare `var form` globally. It should initialize each post request